# What might be the daily experience of someone who does not have an orientation association area?

Tags: neurophilosophy

The orientation association area gives us a sense of our body in time and space.

What would it be like without this part of the brain assuming everything else works normally?

Can the brain separate itself from the totality of everything? Can the person maneuver in the environment? Can the person know "he/she" exists without this tactile sense of separation and ability to identify? Can the person understand "life/death" without this separation?

Comment: I made some edits which you may roll back or continue editing. This might be closed as off-topic here or perhaps too broad, but it might be worth asking at the psychology and neuroscience SE.

Comment: The answer is "No" in theory and in practice a volunteering subject will do.